# Amalgamation of finitely generated finite exponent groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Suppose $C\leq A,B$ are finitely generated groups of finite exponent. Can $A$ and $B$ be [amalgamated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amalgamation_property) over $C$ in a group of finite exponent? What about if $A,B$ are periodic, can we find a periodic amalgam?

Note that if we assume that $A$ and $B$ are finite, then there is a finite amalgam by a classical construction of Neumann.

If we do not assume that the groups be finitely generated, then taking $C$ to be an infinite dimensional vector space over the field with $2$ elements, and $A,B$ to be appropriate expansions of $C$ by involutive automorphisms, we get an example where $A,B$ are of exponent 4 and every amalgam has an element of infinite order.

Thus, if this is true, the proof must use local finiteness, and if not, counterexamples must be (necessarily countably) infinite.

We could try to emulate the counterexample if we could find a f.g. group $C$ of finite exponent (or periodic) with two automorphisms of finite order whose product has infinite order (or generate jointly automorphisms of arbitrarily high order). But even then we would need to ensure that the group generated by $C$ together with each of these automorphisms is still finite exponent/periodic.

(I did not check carefully, but possibly, the conclusion is also true if we assume that $C$ is one of finite, finite index in one of $A,B$, or central in one of $A,B$, but I do not want to assume anything like that.)

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "amalgamated in a group"? Nontrivial amalgamated product (i. e. $C$ does not coincide with either $A$ or $B$) always contains a free subgroup.

Comment: I mean that there are embeddings of $A$ and $B$ into some $D$ which coincide on $C$. Free amalgams won't work, of course.

Comment: Well, then the answer is obviously "yes" for finite exponent case: just take quotient of amalgamated product by the normal subgroup generated by all elements of the form $x^r$, where $r$ is gcd of exponents of $A, B$. In other words, take pushout in the variety consisting of exponent $r$ groups. For periodic case I guess there will be a counterexample; I'd bet that product of carefully chosen Golod-Shafarevich groups over maximal finite subgroups can admit no torsion quotients with both free factors embedded.

Comment: @DenisT: You seem to be claiming that two f.g. groups of exponent $r$ can be amalgamated in a group of exponent $r$. A variant of the infinitely generated example I roughly described in my question shows that this is not true; for any even $n\geq 4$, you can get two f.g. groups of exponent $4$ whose amalgams have exponent at least $n$.

Comment: The varieties of groups for which the factors embed in the pushout with the intersection the amalgamating subgroups seem to be limited and not a lot seems to be known.  There is some on this in Hanna Neumann's book.  My understanding I believe that to have strong amalgamation for a proper variety of groups, all the finite groups in the variety must be abelian, but I might have misunderstood.   I'm not expert

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: It seems (from the comments) that OP uses a nonstandard notion of an amalgam, which is not a pushout.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, His notion is standard in universal algebra at least for groups and semigroups. In the case of a variety if anything works the pushout works but for some varieties the pushout doesn’t work.  The variety doesn’t have the strong amalgamation property.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I don't really care about the pushout, and I don't need disjoint amalgamation. I'm basically asking whether the class of finite exponent/periodic groups has the amalgamation property (and these classes are not varieties in the sense of universal algebra,, are they?). Basically, I'm looking for interesting Fraisse classes of groups. For example, if the amalgam did exist, the class of f.g. recursively presentable finite exponent/periodic groups (or the class of such groups in a a fixed CTM) would probably be Fraisse.

Comment: I was considering the case where you wanted the amalgam to have the same exponent.  Then you would be in the variety case.  I think most of these types of questions are open.  Bernhard Neumann has example where you cannot find a locally finite or periodic amalgam when C is not finite but you seem aware of this and if C is finte, then I think there are no problems finding a locally finite amalgam if A,B are (I'm not sure about periodic)

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I didn't. I was referring to Denis's claim (specifically, pointing out that it's not correct). It was my impression that these are open, but since I'm not a group theorist, I wasn't sure if I'm not missing something well-known to group theorists (especially since I think the latest relevant references I was able to find date from the sixties...). Thanks for the input!

Comment: My impression is that by the seventies many group theorists lost interest in these kinds of things

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: That is what I think, too. Still, it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: Hanna Neumann's book contains information on the free product in a variety (called the *verbal product*), and this is without amalgamation. Then Problem 6 (p42) asks about the existence of this product with amalgamation. Possibly I am miss-interpreting something, but your negative example (and also @AshotMinasyan's answer) gives a negative answer to this problem for the variety of groups of exponent $4$ (or $n$ large and odd, for Minasyan's answer).

Comment: @ADL: I don't think my example can possibly be new. It is a very straightforward variation of an example (itself not very complicated) given (iirc) by B.H. Neumann in the sixties. In the answer, the common exponent is actually $2n^2$, I believe.

Comment: @tomasz Sorry, I was miss-interpreting the problem. It actually asks if such a product *ever* exists. That is, apart from the "obvious" ones (all groups/abelian groups/abelian groups of exponent $n$), is there a variety which has a verbal product with amalgamation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard to construct counter-examples for large exponents.

Consider the following two automorphisms $\xi, \eta$ of the free group $F=F(x,y)$ of rank $2$, defined by
$$\xi(x)=y,~\xi(y)=x \text{ and } \eta(x)=x,~\eta(y)=yx.$$
The composition $\xi \circ \eta \in Aut(F)$ is the so-called Fibonacci automorphism $\varphi$, given by
$$\varphi(x)=y,~\varphi(y)=xy.$$

Now, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the free Burnside group $B(2,n)$, of exponent $n$, is the quotient of $F$ by the verbal subgroup generated by all $n$-th powers. It follows that every automorphism of $F$ induces an automorphism of $B(2,n)$ (there is a natural homomorphism $Aut(F) \to Aut(B(2,n))$, $\alpha \mapsto \bar\alpha$).

Now, take $n$ be to sufficiently large and odd. Then it is known that the Fibonacci automorphism $\bar\varphi$ has infinite order in $Aut(B(2,n))$. This result was proved in
[*Cherepanov, E. A.*, [**Free semigroup in the group of automorphisms of the free Burnside group.**](https://doi.org/10.1081/AGB-200047435), Commun. Algebra 33, No. 2, 539-547 (2005). [ZBL1121.20028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1121.20028).[, and was improved (for smaller  exponents) in
[*Pajlevanyan, Ashot S.*, [**The Fibonacci automorphism of free Burnside groups.**](https://doi.org/10.1051/ita/2011118), RAIRO, Theor. Inform. Appl. 45, No. 3, 301-309 (2011). [ZBL1227.20038](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1227.20038).]

Evidently $\bar\xi$ has order at most $2$ and $\bar\eta$ has order dividing $n$ in $Aut(B(2,n))$, because the order of the image of $x$ divides $n$ (in fact, the orders of $\bar\xi$ and $\bar\eta$ will be exactly $2$ and $n$). Therefore, the semidirect products $G=B(2,n) \rtimes_{\bar\xi} C_2$ and $H=B(2,n)\rtimes_{\bar\eta} C_n$, where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, have exponents dividing $2n$ and $n^2$ respectively. It's easy to see that both $G$ and $H$ are generated by $2$ elements.

However, as the OP suggested in the post, since the composition $\bar \varphi$, of the automorphisms $\bar\xi$ and $\bar \eta$, has infinite order in $Aut(B(2,n))$, the groups $G$ and $H$ cannot be amalgamated over $B(2,n)$ in a periodic group.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid for not knowing the estimate for upper bound of the exponent of a semidirect product. That would've made it easier to find the example, I guess. This is very nice, thanks!

Comment: @tomasz It may be better to think about the estimate in terms normal subgroups: if a group $G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ such that $exp(H)=n$ and $exp(G/H)=k$ then $exp(G)$ divides $kn$. Obviously $exp(G/H)$ divides $|G:H|$.

Comment: You're right, exactly the same argument I had in mind works in this case. Thanks again!